# Image imagejpeg() returns nothing. CakePHP

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, upload

I am modifieng this plug in to save a record of the path and make a thumbnail image and save that aswell http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/srs2012/2012/03/12/ajaxmultiupload_plugin_for_cake_2_0_x_and_2_1
I modified the upload.php in the plugin like this:

```
function save($path, $folder, $filename) {    
    $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
    fclose($input);

    if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
        return false;
    }
    $width = 290; 
    $height = 146;
    $target = fopen($path, "w");  
    //$this->Upload->setImage($this->Image);

    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);  
    fclose($target);
    $val = $this->resizeImage($filename, $filename, $folder, $folder.'/small/', $width, $height, 100);
    $this->saveToDatabase(array('path' => $folder.$filename, 'thumb' => $folder.'/small/'.$filename));

    return true;
}
```

This is the function i made to save:

```
function saveToDatabase($data){
    $this->Image->save($data);
}
```

The following I added to create the thumbnail:

```
function resizeImage($src_img, $dst_img, $src_path2, $dst_path2, $dst_w, $dst_h, $dst_quality){
    //Stop and giving an error if the file does not exists.
    $src_path = 'img/';
    $dst_path = 'img/';
    $src_path .= $src_path2;
    $dst_path .= $dst_path2;
    if(file_exists($src_path . basename($src_img)) == false){
        echo 0;
    }
        //Get variables for the function.
            //complete path of the source image.
    $src_cpl = $src_path . basename($src_img);
    //return $src_cpl;
            //complete path of the destination image.
    $dst_cpl = $dst_path . basename($dst_img);
            //extension excl "." of the source image, in lowercase.
    $src_ext = strtolower(end(explode(".", $src_img)));
            //width and height sizes of the source image.
    list($src_w, $src_h) = getimagesize($src_cpl);

            //get type of image.
    //return 'IETS: '.$src_cpl.' :IETS';  
    $src_type = exif_imagetype($src_cpl);//
    //Checking extension and imagetype of the source image and path.
    if( ($src_ext =="jpg") && ($src_type =="2") ){
        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_cpl);
    }else if( ($src_ext =="jpeg") && ($src_type =="2") ){
        $src_img = imagecreatefromjpeg($src_cpl);
    }else if( ($src_ext =="gif") && ($src_type =="1") ){
        $src_img = imagecreatefromgif($src_cpl);
    }else if( ($src_ext =="png") && ($src_type =="3") ){
        $src_img = imagecreatefrompng($src_cpl);
    }else{
        die('<p>The file "'. $src_img . '" with the extension "' . $src_ext . '" and the imagetype "' . $src_type . '" is not a valid image. Please upload an image with the extension JPG, JPEG, PNG or GIF and has a valid image filetype.</p>');
    }

    //Get heights and width so the image keeps its ratio.
    $x_ratio = $dst_w / $src_w;
    $y_ratio = $dst_h / $src_h;

        if( (($x_ratio > 1) || ($y_ratio > 1)) && ($x_ratio > $y_ratio) ){
        //If one of the sizes of the image is smaller than the destination (normal: more height than width).
        $dst_w = ceil($y_ratio * $src_w);
        $dst_h = $dst_h;
    }elseif( (($x_ratio > 1) || ($y_ratio > 1)) && ($y_ratio > $x_ratio) ){
        //If one of the sizes of the image is smaller than the destination (landscape: more width than height).
        $dst_w = $dst_w;
        $dst_h = ceil($x_ratio * $src_h);
    }elseif (($x_ratio * $src_h) < $dst_h){
        //if the image is landscape (more width than height).
        $dst_h = ceil($x_ratio * $src_h);
        $dst_w = $dst_w;
    }elseif (($x_ratio * $src_h) > $dst_h){
        //if the image is normal (more height than width).
        $dst_h = ceil($x_ratio * $src_h);
        $dst_w = $dst_w;
    }else{
        //if the image is normal (more height than width).
        $dst_w = ceil($y_ratio * $src_w);
        $dst_h = $dst_h;
    }
     // Creating the resized image.
    $dst_img=imagecreatetruecolor($dst_w,$dst_h);
    $result = imagecopyresampled($dst_img,$src_img,0,0,0,0,$dst_w, $dst_h,$src_w,$src_h);

    // Saving the resized image.
    $result2 = imagejpeg($dst_img,$dst_cpl,$dst_quality);
    return 'dfdfhdfhhgfddghhgffddghdghhdgghgfhdh: '.$result.'|||asdasda'.$result2;

    // Cleaning the memory.
    imagedestroy($src_img);
    imagedestroy($dst_img);

}

enter code here
```

Now I already used this code on the same server and it worked perfectly fine. But in my return value i get the following:

```
[uploader] responseText = dfdfhdfhhgfddghhgffddghdghhdgghgfhdh: 1|||asdasda{"success":true}
```

The function imagejpeg does not return anything.

Now what could be wrong? I am only an intern and I can't figure out what is wrong.

Greetings,
Harm.
bump?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php - I think, that you have problem in function imagejpeg - see parameter filename.

If there will be more problems, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gd-info.php

Comment: The path is the following: img/uploads/Projects/2//small/1336986225.jpg ($dst_cpl) and this is what i get with the gd_info:
["GIF Read Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["GIF Create Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["JPEG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["PNG Support"]=>
  bool(true)
Thing is that on the same server with the same code in an another componement it does work...

Comment: You have 2 slashes in it:  img/uploads/Projects/2 ==> // <== small/1336986225.jpg - some servers may not understand this.

Comment: No that isn't the problem. I double checked by setting the $dst_cpl to a hard-coded string. 
Besides the code works on the same server in an another compoment as mentioned before, the path is the same there.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not familiar with this function... Where should I put it and what should I do afterwards?

Comment: This function take care about printing warnings and errors. Parameter -1 = prtint all. Put that on begining of srcipt.

Comment: Okay I pasted the line above my class and I got this back in my debug console: 
<b>Warning</b>:  unlink(C:\xampp\htdocs\axance\app\tmp\cache\persistent\myapp_cake_core_cake_nl) [<a href='function.unlink'>function.unlink</a>]: Permission denied in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\axance\lib\Cake\Cache\Engine\FileEngine.php</b> on line <b>247</b><br />
A:img/uploads/Projects/2//small/133700180047.jpg{"success":true}

Comment: So i added the right permissions to my xampp/tmp folder and i do not get this error. But still there's no uploading done anymore. (not in my old script aswell)

Comment: $result2 = imagejpeg($dst_img, str_replace('//','/',$dst_cpl), $dst_quality);

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I tried the line you posted and unfortunately it doesn't work.